# VBA: How to add formula to DataValidation

Tags: excel, vba, tensorflow-data-validation

I want to add DataValidation to range (more than one Cell)
Formula:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("System_General_Cargo[[#Headers];[Location]]");MATCH(B20;INDIRECT("System_General_Cargo[Location]");0);1;COUNTIF(INDIRECT("System_General_Cargo[Location]");B20);1)
```

- First Question: What is the code
- Second Question: I want to replace B20 (because its range) with @Column2 or [@Column2]. I can't enter it even without VBA.

Error:

> We found problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert function on the formula tab.......

VBA code replace B20 with dynamic cell address